# Likes on original post instead of the shared one

Tags: facebook

When I share a post from a fan page on Facebook, how can I make likes appear on the original post instead of on my share?

Answer (score -3):

Just don't show the complete post, force them to open the original post and thus you can get some likes easily.

Comment: By showing them a link with some text? Perhaps you can give an example?